# Open a specific tab on page load using JavaScript to "click" with 2 tabbed menus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have 2 tab menus on the page and allow for the first tab to be open upon page load. I was able to figure it out for the first menu but have difficulties with the second. Should I use a different ID for the second tabbed menu?

Here's the page: https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=4182

```js
<script>
function openMembership(evt, membershipName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(membershipName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
 // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background-color: #003366;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
color: white;
    border: none;
  float: left;tabee   
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #669966;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #669966;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="text-align: center;">NEW MEMBERSHIP APPLICATIONS</h3>
<!-- Member Type 1 --><!-- Tab Links -->

<div class="tab"><button class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openMembership(event, 'Candidate')">Candidate</button><button class="tablinks" onclick="openMembership(event, 'Active')">Active &amp; International Active</button><button class="tablinks" onclick="openMembership(event, 'Associate')">Associate</button></div>
<!-- Tab content --><!-- Type 1 -->

<div class="tabcontent" id="Candidate">
<h3>Candidate</h3>

<p>Those eligible for this membership status are Residents, Fellows-in-training, and former Fellows whose training is completed and are board eligible.</p>

<p>Required Membership application materials:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Completed application with payment</li>
    <li>Curriculum Vitae</li>
    <li>1 written letter of recommendation from a NANOS Fellow</li>
    <li>Copy of Board USMLE (if applicable)</li>
</ul>

<p>Candidate Membership pricing:<br />
Residents: $125 (JNO electronic version only; no print copy)<br />
Fellows-in-Training/Board Eligible: $225 + $50 initiation fee (JNO electronic version only; no print copy)<br />
<br />
Click on the link below that corresponds to your level of training to access the online Candidate Membership applications.</p>

<ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageID=3796/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageID=3796" target="_blank">Resident</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageID=3797/pages/index.cfm?pageID=3797" target="_blank">Fellow-in-Training</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Type 2 -->

<div class="tabcontent" id="Active">
<h3>Active &amp; International Active:</h3>

<p>Those eligible for ACTIVE membership status have been certified in Neurology by the American Board of Psychiatry and Neurology, or in Neurosurgery by the American Board of Neurosurgery, or in Ophthalmology by the American Board of Ophthalmology, or in Neurology by the American Osteopathic Board of Neurology and Psychiatry, or in Ophthalmology by the American Osteopathic Colleges of Ophthalmology and Otolaryngology, Head and Neck Surgery, or in Neurology, Neurosurgery or Ophthalmology by the Royal College of Physicians and Surgeons of Canada.</p>

<p>Those eligible for INTERNATIONAL ACTIVE membership status have graduated from a foreign medical school recognized by the World Health Organization (WHO) and who show evidence of having passed the requirements for license to practice medicine in their home country or country of residence; AND who have completed postgraduate training in Neurology, Ophthalmology or Neurosurgery who are certified by the licensing authority in their country or by an internationally-recognized agency that grants accreditation in these specialties, OR who have been recognized specialists in Neuro-Ophthalmology in their country for at least five years; and have achieved distinction in clinical practice, teaching or research</p>

<p>Required Membership application materials:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Completed application with payment</li>
    <li>Curriculum Vitae</li>
    <li>1 written letter of recommendation from a NANOS Fellow</li>
    <li>Copy of US/International Board Certification</li>
</ul>

<p>Active/International Active Membership pricing: $425 + $50 initiation fee (JNO electronic version and print copy).<br />
Click on the link below to access the online Active/International Active Membership application.</p>

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageID=3386">Active/International Active Member</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Type 3 -->

<div class="tabcontent" id="Associate">
<h3>Associate</h3>

<p>Those eligible for this membership status have graduated from any medical school recognized by the World Health Organization (WHO), who show evidence of having passed the requirements for license to practice medicine in their home country or country of residence and who are practicing in clinical specialties of Neurology, Neurosurgery or Ophthalmology or in other fields related to Neuro-Ophthalmology; or those Persons, including physicians or holders of an advanced degree, practicing or engaged in non-clinical fields relating to Neuro-Ophthalmology.</p>

<p>Required Membership application materials:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Completed application with payment</li>
    <li>Curriculum Vitae</li>
    <li>1 written letter of recommendation from a NANOS Fellow</li>
    <li>Copy of US/International Board Certification</li>
</ul>

<p>Associate Membership pricing: $425 + $50 initiation fee (JNO electronic version and print copy)<br />
Click on the link below to access the online Associate Membership application.</p>

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageID=3386">Associate Member</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Member Status Updates -->

<hr />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">MEMBER STATUS UPDATES</h3>
<!-- Tab Links -->

<div class="tab"><button class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openMembership(event, 'Fellow')">(International) Fellow</button><button class="tablinks" onclick="openMembership(event, 'Senior')">Senior &amp; Senior Fellow</button><button class="tablinks" onclick="openMembership(event, 'International Senior')">International Senior &amp; Senior Fellow</button></div>
<!-- Member Update 1 -->

<div class="tabcontent" id="Fellow">
<h3>Fellow or International Fellow</h3>

<p>Those eligible for this membership status are NANOS Active Members who have been a member for minimum of 3 years and have attended a minimum of 5 NANOS Annual Meetings. Eligible candidates must also have demonstrated special achievement in clinical Neuro-Ophthalmology and have completed one year of Neuro-Ophthalmology Fellowship, or have practiced clinical Neuro-Ophthalmology or have performed research in Neuro-Ophthalmology for 3 years.</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Required Fellow Membership Status application materials:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Completed application</li>
    <li>Curriculum Vitae with a cover letter</li>
    <li>2 written letters of recommendation from NANOS Fellows</li>
</ul>

<p>Click on the link below to download the Fellow and International Fellow Status Membership application.</p>

<ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/files/Fellow%20Application%202016.pdf" target="_blank">Fellow and International Fellow </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Member Update 2 -->

<div class="tabcontent" id="Senior">
<h3>Senior or Senior Fellow</h3>

<p>Those eligible for this membership status are over 65 years old, disabled, or fully retired, and have been a member for a minimum of 5 years.</p>

<p>Required Senior Membership Status application materials:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Written letter addressed to the NANOS Membership Committee requesting senior status including qualifications</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Member Update 3 -->

<div class="tabcontent" id="International Senior">
<h3>International Senior or Senior Fellow</h3>

<p>Those eligible for this membership status are over 65 years old, disabled, or fully retired, and have been a member for a minimum of 5 years.</p>

<p>Required Senior Membership Status application materials:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Written letter addressed to the NANOS Membership Committee requesting senior status including qualifications</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "Should I use a different ID for the second tabbed menu?" Yes, ID must be unique. Use a class instead

Comment: I added a class "DefaultOpen" and changed my script to activate the click event but the second menu is still not clicked. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Here's the revised script and the html of the button was updated accordingly (from ID to class): 
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();  
document.getElementByClass("defaultOpen").click();